# How to display only the last digit of a number?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm new to Android and Java.

I'm creating a countdown timer and would like to display the remaining time as:

> minutes:seconds.deciseconds

I've figured out the minutes and seconds, but I'm stuck on the deciseconds?

```
textViewShowTime.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 600)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", (seconds / 10) % 60)
                        + "." + String.format("%01d", seconds));
```

The tick counts down correctly at decisecond intervals, but I can't figure out how to only display the last digit?

Comment: Quick google search... `seconds * 10  =  deciseconds`

Comment: A decisecond = 0.1 second

Comment: So value of the `seconds` variable is not actually a "second" value, but a "decisecond" value? **Very bad name** for that variable! It should be named `deciseconds`. [*Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the casual observer the intent of its use.*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Please try to do some google search before asking a question

Comment: No, the seconds value is seconds, but I needed to display the deciseconds in the countdown timer.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer:

```
 textViewShowTime.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 600)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", (seconds / 10) % 60)
                        + "." + String.format("%01d", seconds % 10));
```

Comment: How is this correct? If `seconds` is an integer (assuming from using `%d` to format), then how is there a decimal place? That would just show the "ones" place.

Comment: Does `seconds` actually represent units of deciseconds? Then it would make sense.

Comment: If `seconds` is integral, then there will be no deciseconds. If seconds is floating-value, the correct value to use is `(seconds * 10) % 10`

Comment: `seconds` is a long